# Return Each Item with the Lowest Value from the Inner Array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Speaking people I'm here thinking of logic to return only each item with its lowest value proposition, if json.

```
{
 requester: "test",
 orderitems: [ 
                 {
                   description: "testitem1",
                   proposals: [
                                 {
                                   company: "company1",
                                   value: 10
                                 },
                                 {
                                   company: "company2",
                                   value: 5
                                 }
                   ]
                 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your available MongoDB server version:

You either implement using [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) with MongoDB 3.4 as the shortest way to do this:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "orderitems": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$orderitems",
        "as": "o",
        "in": { 
          "description": "$$o.description",
          "proposals": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$$o.proposals",
              { "$indexOfArray": [
                "$$o.proposals.value",
                { "$min": "$$o.proposals.value" }
              ]}
            ]    
          }
        }
      }   
    }
  }}
])
```

Or with MongoDB 3.2 you can [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and take the first matching element with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/):

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "orderitems": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$orderitems",
        "as": "o",
        "in": { 
          "description": "$$o.description",
          "proposals": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              { "$filter": {
                "input": "$$o.proposals",
                "cond": { "$eq": ["$$this.value",{ "$min": "$$o.proposals.value" }] }
              }},
              0
            ]    
          }
        }
      }   
    }
  }}
])
```

And it honestly would be a pain to try and implement in any version lower than that.

The essential principle is matching based on the value returned by [`$min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/), which did get a change in MongoDB 3.2 so it can be used to return the "minimum" value from any array of values rather than just as an "accumulator" in aggregation [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

> *Changed in version 3.2*: $min is available in the $group and $project stages. In previous versions of MongoDB, $min is available in the $group stage only.

So the general case is we match the array entry by the returned value either from the matching index of [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) or by whatever is returned as matching array entries of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).

Depending on the method chosen, either the 'matched index' is fed to [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to extract the array value at that index, or the `0` index is used to get the "first" element from the "filtered list".

Either approach returns:

```
{
    "requester" : "test",
    "orderitems" : [ 
        {
            "description" : "testitem1",
            "proposals" : {
                "company" : "company2",
                "value" : 5.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```